# AWS Data Structure and Stack Suggestion for highly filterable data

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-dynamodb, aws-appsync

Firstly, let me know if I should place this in a different Community. It is programming related but less than I would prefer.

I am creating a mobile app based which I intend to base on AWS App Sync unless I can determine it is a poor fit.

I want to store a fairly large set of data, say a half million records.

From these records, I need to be able to grab all entries based on a tag and page them from the larger set.

An example of this data would be:

```
{
   "name":"Product123",
   "tags":[
      {
         "name":"1880",
         "type":"year",
         "value":7092
      },
      {
         "name":"f",
         "type":"gender",
         "value":4120692
      }
   ]
}
```

Various objects may or may not have a specific tag but may have up to 500 tags or more (the seed of initial data has 130 tags). My filter would ignore them if they did not match but return them if they did.

In reading about Query vs Scan on DyanmoDB, I feel like my current data structure would require mostly scanning and be in-efficient. Efficiency is only a real restriction due to cost.

With cost in mind, I will focus on the cost per user to access this data in filtered sets. Say 100,000 users for now each filtering and paging data many times a day.

Comment: Can the tag names be unique? In other words, an item can contain only one tag with "name":"f"?

Comment: Maybe, I have not thought of all cases yet. That is why for now type is included but may eventually be removed. Plus it lets me geoup certain tags and could provide a filter list by category.

Comment: If tag name is unique then you can think about designing the table with name as partition key and tagname as sort key and break your item into N items each having name, tagname, tagtype, tagvalue. Then you can create a local secondary index with partition key as name and tagtype as sortkey (assuming tagtype is also unique)

Answer (score 0):

Your concept of tags doesn't sound too different from the concept of Cognito User Pools' groups with AppSync [(docs)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-authorization) - authentication based on groups will only return items allowed for groups that the user making the request is in. Cognito's default group limit is 25 per user pool, so while convenient out of the box, it wouldn't itself help you much. Instead, it's interesting just because it's similar conceptually, and can give you insight by looking at how it works internally.

If you go into the AppSync console and set up a request mapping template for groups auth, you'll see that it uses a scan and the contains operation. Doing something similar would probably be your best bet here, if you really want to use Dynamo. If you find that prohibitively costly, you could use a Lambda data source, which allows you to use any data store, if you have one in mind that's a little more flexible for this type of action.